# Knockout Mapping Issue

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

i am new to Ko and mapping plugin.

I have to read data from weather api of a city from http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=Vancouver,%20ca

and display it in UI using ko and mapping.

However I have a issue in mapping and due to that the data is not appearing in UI.

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(models, self.ArrayOfModels);
http://jsfiddle.net/balain/ENMGp/536/
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: code is in http://jsfiddle.net/balain/ENMGp/536/

Comment: `ko.mapping.fromJS(models, {}, self.ArrayOfModels);`

Comment: Thank you Tomalak for your help. But still the data not appearing in UI. <div data-bind="foreach: ArrayOfModels">
    <div data-bind="text: cod"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: message"></div>
</div>Am i doing something wrong in data-binding. Can you see my fiddle pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balain/ENMGp/536/) uses a *truly* outdated version of knockout (1.2.1 is ancient). I've updated it to 3.2.0. Also you don't need the jQuery template plugin for anything. I've removed it.

Next, I would recommend constructing your view models in such a way that they take care of themselves, including bootstrapping from init data. Like so:

```
// Contained Model
function SearchResultModel(init) {
    // data
    this.message = ko.observable();
    this.cod = ko.observable();
    this.city_id = ko.observable();
    this.calctime = ko.observable();
    this.cnt = ko.observable();
    this.list = ko.observableArray();

    // init
    ko.mapping.fromJS(init, {}, this);
}
```

Next, you can condense your Ajax request quite a bit:

```
// View Model
function WeatherViewModel(init) {
    var self = this;

    // data
    self.city = ko.observable();
    self.searchResult = ko.observable(new SearchResultModel());

    // methods
    self.getWeatherByCity = function () {
        var city = self.city()
        if (city) {
            $.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city', {
                q: city
            }).done(function(data) {
                self.searchResult(new SearchResultModel(data));
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("could not get weather data!");
            });
        } else {
            // no city? => empty the search result
            self.searchResult(new SearchResultModel());
        }
    };

    // init
    ko.mapping.fromJS(init, {}, self);
}
```

init with sample data:

```
ko.applyBindings(new WeatherViewModel({
    city: "Vancouver, CA"
}));
```

and you are good to go: http://jsfiddle.net/ENMGp/539/.

Since you tagged this [knockout-2.0] (I have no idea why you would want that for a new project), I've created a 2.0 compatible version: http://jsfiddle.net/ENMGp/540/. The code is the same, but knockout 2.0 does not work with jQuery 1.9+, so I had to downgrade both libraries. FWIW, I'd recommend going with a current release of knockout.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ybo0zrwh/

```
this.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function(models) {
    self.ArrayOfModels.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(models));
};
```

It does not look like you are getting back an array of objects from the server.  You can map the single object and then push it onto your observable array.